# Is there an alternative to Pivotal Tracker that uses real time estimates?

Tags: project-management, agile

I like Pivotal Tracker, however I do not agree with their approach of using a "star" system, rather than asking programmers to provide real time estimates.  I think there should be accountability so that programmers learn to get better about providing time estimates.  The star system appears designed to insulate developers from this, which I think is counter-productive.

Is there something like Pivotal Tracker where programmers provide real time estimates?

I would also like something that has a report which shows the total estimated time for all outstanding issues, on a per-programmer basis.

In the past we rolled our own using Trac, but would prefer a more modern solution.  I'm considering using Github Issues (we already use Github for source control), and building some tools that use the Github Issues API to facilitate per-issue time estimates in the manner I've described.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

TargetProcess ([www.targetprocess.com](http://www.targetprocess.com/3)) is the cleanest and most fluid tool I've found.

Answer (score 3):

make it work for you:   just go to your pivotal tracker project's settings and choose custom estimates, or maybe Fibonacci, and use that for hour/day estimations

Answer (score 2):

Check out Assembla Agile Planner - it s very similar and free for unlimited users/tasks: http://www.assembla.com/catalog/tag/Free

Answer (score 2):

Try [Breeze](http://letsbreeze.com), it allows you to add estimates (in hours) and also log work done under every task, plus it has a time tracker built in. Reports are also available, showing totals for projects and work done per task. You can also export the reports to CSV.
Overall it has a similar Kanban style layout and system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview#) or [Version one](http://www.versionone.com/).

JIRA : very powerful and flexible , it supports Scrum , kanban or you can invent your customized issue tracking workflow.

Version one : very organized and has an easy workflow (Scrum only) & supports managing dependency of user stories & tasks.

Finally , Github is good tool for managing projects as well but it will not be a good solution for you because you can not add an estimate for issues you can only set a dead line for a milestone also it has some constraints that you should be aware of while choosing.

- You can only one level of tasks , there is no nesting which will make it tricky to manage a user story and its sub-tasks - a work around for that we use labels.
- You  can not delete an issue , you can only archive it or close it.
- You can not attach an image or file directly to it , you'll have to do it using the Markdown syntax and push the images to the repository first.

Comment: Jira is great if you have at least 1GB of RAM to spare on your server. Otherwise you are stuck using the hosted version - which is nice but not nearly as flexible. Think Wordpress.com vs self-hosted.